# Will Archer T6E AC1300 ever get a driver upstream?

Tags: drivers, wireless, tp-link

I have this wifi card: https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/pci-adapter/archer-t6e/

Currently on Ubuntu 22.04, it needs a proprietary driver for its AC1300 chip.

Will Ubuntu ever have the open source version of it? There are some on the web like https://github.com/nyetwurk/linux-wifi-88x2bu-driver but they never get upstream